# Unambigous behaviour during print in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, printf

The print statement given below executes correctly when I remove the parentheses and produces an error `syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'` when parentheses are kept. Any help would be appreciated since I am new to Ruby

```
print "Enter name: "
name=gets
puts name
puts "Enter first number"
num1=gets
puts "Enter Second number"
num2=gets
result=Integer(num1)+Integer(num2)
print ("The addition of "+num1.chomp+" and " + num2.chomp+ " is ",result)
```

Comment: Why are you putting the result after a comma instead of concatenating it? Why are you concatenating instead of using string interpolation?

Comment: @DaveNewton I tried concatenating it using + operator but that too would produce an error,even after removing paranthesis the error lasts.This way it works if i remove paranthesis,i dont understand why this happens?

Comment: If you're going to use method-calling-parentheses in Ruby then you can't put a space between the method name and the `(`, if there is a space there then the parentheses are interpreted as expression-grouping-parentheses and since there is no comma operator in Ruby, you get a syntax error. Say `print expr1, expr2` or print(expr1, expr2)`.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks,why does the + operator does not work over here instead of , ?

Comment: @query: because `result` is a number. It makes no sense to add a string and a number. What would the result even be? A string? Which one? A number? Which one? What is `'hello' + 1`? Is it one more than hello? What does that even mean?

Comment: `print "The addition of "+num1.chomp+" and " + num2.chomp+ " is ",result` works fine as does `print("The addition of "+num1.chomp+" and " + num2.chomp+ " is ",result)`. If you mean `print 'some string' + result` then you'll get an error because `String#+` doesn't know what to do with a number (unlike various other languages that will convert the number to a string on their own).

Comment: @JörgWMittag Other languages will implicitly convert the number to a string before concatenating so thinking that `'a' + 11` should be `'a11'` is understandable and no cause for drama.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Welcome to Javascript! `'1' + 1` is `'11'` and `'1' - 1` is `0` :D

Comment: @muistooshort : This is the design decision that bothers me the most with Javascript for example. Better return something than throw an exception! So let's implicitely convert strings to ints, ints to strings, lists to strings and never, ever complain about type error! There should be more drama IMHO.

Comment: @EricDuminil Every language is stupid, confusing, and full of nonsense and brain damage. There's already far too much drama in the programming world IMO.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Ruby does allow `'hello'.concat(33)`, resulting in `"hello!"`.

Comment: IMO, `String` should simply not respond to arithmetic operators. `String#+` should be `String#concat`, `String#concat` should be `String#append` and `String#*` should be `String#repeat`.

Comment: @muistooshort : I meant to say that Javascript should answer with more drama when an input is ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to achieve what you want:

- get rid of the space between `print` and `(`

  `print("The addition of " + num1.chomp + " and " + num2.chomp + " is ",  result)`
- use `+` to concatenate the strings; this will require you to use `to_s` to convert the numeric value `result` into a string:

  `print("The addition of " + num1.chomp + " and " + num2.chomp + " is " + result.to_s)`
- use string interpolation:

  `print("The addition of #{num1.chomp} and #{num2.chomp} is #{result}")`

Comment: Thanks Frank,This really helped.anyway nice quote on your profile,really liked it :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a Python background? This code looks like Python written in Ruby ;)

```
print 'Enter first number: '
num1 = gets.to_i
print 'Enter Second number: '
num2 = gets.to_i
puts format('The addition of %d and %d is %d', num1, num2, num1 + num2)
```

`String#to_i` is more often used than `Integer()`. Also, both `Integer()` and `to_i` ignore newlines, so you don't need to call `chomp`.

[`Kernel#format`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-format) is a good and fast way to integrate variables in a string. It uses the same format as C/Python/Java/...

Comment: [`Integer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) also ignores a trailing newline.

Comment: No i have cpp background,Thanks for the help mate!

Answer (score 0):

```
print "Enter name: "
name=gets.strip   ##strip method removes unnecessary spaces from start & End
puts "Enter first number"
num1=gets.strip.to_i   ##convert string number into Int
puts "Enter Second number"
num2=gets.strip.to_i
result=num1+num2
print "The addition: #{num1} + #{num2} = #{result}"   ##String interpolation.
```

Comment: What is the added value of your answer compared to the 2 previous ones?